# How to implement static classes in c++?

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-classes

I was wanting to implement a simple static class that calculates the pow value of an integer in c++ while practicing. So my codes here:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MATH_H
#define MATH_H
static class Math
{
    public:
        static int pow(int,int);
};


#endif /* MATH_H */
```

And the implemetation of pow function:

```
#include "Math.h"

int Math::pow(int base, int exp){
    if(exp==1)
        return base;
    else if(exp%2==0)
        return pow(base,exp/2)*pow(base,exp/2);
    else
        return pow(base,exp/2)*pow(base,exp/2)*base;
}
```

But the cygwin compiler is throwing compilation error:

```
In file included from Math.cpp:16:0:
Math.h:16:1: error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions
 static class Math
 ^~~~~~
```

Please help me solve my problem.[image: Here are the Microsoft course's official documents from where I have been taught that there are static classes in c++]

Comment: C++ doesn't have static classes. But it looks like all you need is a function.

Comment: And perhaps you want that function in a *namespace*

Comment: As an aside, `<cmath>` already has a `pow` function.

Comment: Remove the `static` before `class Math`.

Comment: BTW, there is a `std::pow` function.  If you want to use your function, prefix with `Math::`, e.g. `Math::pow`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ does not have "static classes" as they formally exist in other languages.  You can, however, delete the default constructor (C++ >= 11) or make it private and unimplemented (C++ < 11) which has the same effect of making the type not constructible:

```
// C++ >= 11
class Math
{
public:
    Math() = delete;
};

// C++ < 11
class Math
{
private:
    Math(); // leave unimplemented
};
```

With this code, the line `Math m;` will fail:

> (C++ >= 11) `error: use of deleted function 'Math::Math()'`
>
> (C++ < 11) `error: 'Math::Math()' is private within this context`

However, "static classes" are mostly an anti-pattern in C++ and free functions should be preferred.  (There are some cases where static classes can be useful, particularly when doing template metaprogramming.  If you're not doing that then you almost certainly don't need a static class.)

Consider instead declaring the functions in a namespace:

```
namespace math {
    int pow(int, int);
}
```

Comment: But Microsoft is presenting a course on the Edx platform and they are writing such static class containing c++ codes in Visual studio.  :(

Comment: @SaswataMishra Are you sure that they aren't using the C++/CLI language? Do you see `ref class` anywhere?

Comment: Still haven't seen `ref class`. But yea, they are using c++.

Comment: or maybe is that about c#? can you share the link?

Comment: @SaswataMishra It's entirely possible that the example code you were shown is incorrect. It's also possible that Microsoft's C++ compiler accepts non-standard things that no other compiler does... it wouldn't be the first time. __Regardless, `static class` is invalid C++ according to the standard.__ Whether Microsoft's compiler accepts it is their problem.

Comment: Man, the name of the course is intermediate c++. -_- And here's the link: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV210.2x+3T2019/courseware/b9ff5ae5be1c4f3281b9931e0972838c/dc2cd274cb0c4bbaa1d32a218a7f49c8/2?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMicrosoft%2BDEV210.2x%2B3T2019%2Btype%40html%2Bblock%400defb6f07099407288e1545d9edd484c

Comment: @cdhowie yes, it is entirely possible that Microsoft has a different c++ compiler.

Comment: @SaswataMishra I'm not saying "different compiler," there's lots of different compilers. It appears that Microsoft may have added a language construct that is simply _not present in standard C++._ If you are learning this feature then you __are not learning C++!__ Rather, __you are learning "Microsoft C++."__ Can you post a screenshot of where you have seen this code?

Comment: I also seriously question the quality of any C++ course that even teaches about classes that aren't constructable. This is _not_ something you should use in C++ unless you have a _very good reason_ which is almost always template metaprogramming. __Using an unconstructable class as a container for functions is wrong in C++.__ Languages like C# have this feature because they doesn't support free functions at all.

Comment: @cdhowie how to add a screenshot? :!

Comment: @SaswataMishra If you copy a screenshot with the print-screen button on your keyboard, you should be able to paste it directly into your question while editing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200916/discussion-between-saswata-mishra-and-cdhowie).